# Callback, which fires on every user action

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I would like to implement a timeout functionality in an AngularJS web app.  Whenever a user does anything, a callback sets the timer to 10 minutes.  When this timer expires on the client-side, a timeout request is sent to the server.

How can I implement a callback which fires from every user action?  Maybe register onclick and onkeydown listener on the whole page/window?

Comment: Why do you want to implement such thing?

Comment: In case the user walks away from the computer and forgets to log out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle does what I need

Answer (score 0):

According to the angular docs for [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope):

> If you want to be notified whenever $digest() is called, you can
>   register a watchExpression function with $watch() with no listener.

I am not sure if `$digest` is called on *every* user action but it might be a good place to start.

FYI - How I implement a User time-out is as follows:

1. Authenticate user via server side API
2. Have API store the user in a cache with sliding expiration and pass back a session token
3. Have each secured API end-point require a session token and use this to fetch the User from the cache thus resetting the expiration timer.
4. If the User does not exist in the cache return a 403 forbidden error which your client code handles, presumably by sending the user back to login page. Actually I return a custom 403 that has a specific 'User Timeout' code and message so my client can handle the time-out gracefully.

This should work fine for most Single Page Apps because pretty much anything the user does causes a state change and most state changes involve a call to the server to fetch or save stuff. It misses out on minor user actions but in I have found that the real world use of this technique has sufficient resolution to be effective.

Comment: I tried $rootScope.$watch(func). Unfortunately, it gets called without user action because the client also polls the server for information.